# Two questions about inhomogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $N(t)$ be an inhomogeneous Poisson process with a intensity function:
$$\lambda(t)=3t+1,\ for\ \ 0\leq t\leq 5,$$
$$\lambda(t)=3\ for\ \ t>5$$
I need to calculate:

1. $E(N(6)-N(3)|N(2)=3)$
2. $P(N(6)-N(4)=k),\ k=0,1,\dots$

Here's my approach:
$$E(N(6)-N(3)|N(2)=3)=E(N(6)-N(3)|N(2)-N(0)=3)=E(N(6)-N(3))=\int_3^6\lambda(y)dy=$$
$$=\int_3^5 3y+1\ dy+ \int_5^6 3\ dy= \frac{3y^2}{2}+y|_{y=3}^{y=5}+3y|_{y=5}^{y=6}=26+3=29$$
And for the second one:
$$P(N(6)-N(4)=k)=e^{-(m(6)-m(4))}\frac{(m(6)-m(4))^k}{k!}$$
We have $m(t)=\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy$, so:
$$m(4)=\int_0^43y+1\ dy=\frac{3y^2}{2}+y|_{y=4}=\frac{3\cdot 16}{2}+4=28$$
$$m(6)=\int_0^53y+1\ dy+\int_5^63\ dy=\frac{3y^2}{2}+y|_{y=5}+3y|_{y=5}^{y=6}=\frac{3\cdot 36}{2}+6+(18-15)=54+6+3=63.$$
Threfore we have
$$P(N(6)-N(4)=k)=e^{-(63-28)}\frac{(63-28)^k}{k!}=e^{-35}\frac{35^k}{k!}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you know how to integrate $\lambda(y)$ over any given interval it looks correct.